# Wildfly 8: are ejb remote proxy thread safe?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

I have the following situation, in a client ear application there is CDI  `@ApplicationScoped` bean which performs a remote SLSB lookup on `@PostConstruct` callback and caches the obtained proxy:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Typed({ ServiceInterface.class })
public class RemoteServiceProxy implements ServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * Remote service.
     */
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public RemoteServiceProxy()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * PostConstruct callback.
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException
     *             Error while looking up remote proxy
     */
    @PostConstruct
    protected void onPostConstruct()
    {
        try
        {
            remoteService = serviceLocator.lookup(ActivityRemoteEntityService.class);

            Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
            jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
            jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");

            Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);

            remoteService = (RemoteService) context.lookup(
                "application.backend/application.backend-service//RemoteServiceImpl!com.application.remote.RemoteService");
        } catch (NamingException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    ... 

}
```

I would like to know if the cached proxy in the field `remoteService` is thread-safe, so the `RemoteServiceProxy` can be annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`, or I have to perform a new proxy lookup for each invocation? Or is a best to use `@Stateless`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB 3.2 Specification has the following to say:

**3.4.9 Concurrent Access to Session Bean References**

It is permissible to acquire a session bean reference and attempt to invoke the same reference object concurrently from multiple threads. However, the resulting client behavior on each thread depends on the concurrency semantics of the target bean. See Section 4.3.13 and Section 4.8.5 for details of the concurrency behavior for session beans.

§4.3.13 basically says that concurrent calls to session beans will be serialised by the container.

§4.8.5 describes the semantics around concurrent access to Singleton Session beans.

Therefore, to be compliant a remote proxy would need to be inherently thread safe as it must follow the semantics required for a "session bean reference".

That said, if you store such a reference in a `@Singleton` EJB, then this reference will only ever be able to concurrently handle a single method call at a time (because such calls are "serialized"). This will likely result in an undesirable bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my doubt is if it's safe to store the wildfly proxy reference in a singleton bean (CDI ApplicationScoped), which is concurrently accessed, in other words is the wildfly proxy implementation thread-safe?

Comment: It's not the @Singleton that controls the concurrency, it's the session bean. One session bean reference (your proxy) => One session bean instance